# Finding the total area between curve and x-axis over a closed interval

Tags: integration, curves, riemann-integration

> Find the total area between $f(x)=x^3-x$ and the x-axis on the
>   interval $[0,3]$.

Here is my work:
$$\int_{0}^{3}(x^3-x)dx$$
$$\left(\frac{(3)^4}{4}-\frac{(3)^2}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{(0)^4}{4}-\frac{(0)^2}{2}\right) = \frac{63}{4}$$

When I submitted this answer, it was marked as incorrect, why?

Comment: Do you mean total *signed* area or total area?

Comment: @user658409 I'm not sure, that was all the information I was given in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct indeed we have

$$\int_{0}^{3}(x^3-x)dx=\left[\frac{x^4}4-\frac{x^2}2\right]_{0}^{3}=\frac{81}4-\frac 9 2=\frac{63}4$$

but maybe you are requested to find not the signed area but the effective area and since $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ changes sign in the interval we have

$$A=\int_{0}^{3}|x^3-x|dx=\int_{0}^{1}(x-x^3) \,dx+\int_{1}^{3} (x^3-x)\, dx=\frac{65}4$$

Comment: That answer was incorrect when I submitted it.

Comment: Ah ok maybe you were requested to find the effective area. I fix that.

Comment: @user505767 So the effective area is the area of each critical point to the to x-axis added together? And what would be the signed area?

Comment: @maxgonz By the defined integral we compute with + sign the area above the $x$ axis and with - sign the area below. For e.g. think to $$\int_{-1}^1 x dx =0$$ but $$\int_{-1}^1 |x| dx =1$$